# How to understand (and translate) this magic spell?

Tags: translation

Currently I am trying to translate a video that's supposed to be a parody of some Japanese kids show.

At some point the character uses a magic spell and it gives me a hard time on more than one level: https://vid.me/necA

1. I can't really hear what the girl says exactly. 
   I came up with

   > じゃあいつもの魔法を使うよ：テラ、テラ、テラ、くるりんパ。

   Here, "Terra" is the place where they are teleporting, but it's the final part that puzzles me.
   For more context, here's the full video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTwLaJhmr40
2. I can't really tell if it's supposed to be a reference to pop culture or some other well-known thing in Japan and finally, I feel like it's a little bit harder to translate these special phrases compared to the sentences we generally hear, so I could greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My kinda question, this is, sadly....

1. ***You are hearing the magic spell correctly***.  To be picky, we tend to pronounce the last syllable as 「パッ」 rather than the plain 「パ」.  The pink character in the video pronounces it 「パッ」 as well.
2. 「くるりんパ（ッ）」 consisits of ***two onomatopoeias***.  Conquer our  onomatopoeias (and particles) and you will conquer our language, trust me.

「くるり（ん）」 is a very common onomatopoeia to describe a thing's circular or rotating motion as in rotating a magic wand.

「パ（ッ）」 is an onomatopoeia describing a thing's movement or appearance ***all of a sudden***.  Use a magic and something will happen all of a sudden, won't it?  The two "guys" suddenly got transported into the building/offices, correct?

The use of the magic spell in the video should not be a reference to a particular phenomenon in our pop culture.  We all have been hearing this spell in stories since childhood.

If my life depended on translating this spell, I might go with:

> "Round and round and here we go!"